# weblogic threads FAT LOCK weblogic.socket.Muxer STUCK BEA-002936 maximum thread constraint ClusterMessaging is reached

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I just had some random alert on my weblogic server 10.3.6 " "

In the full thread dump I have (active status)

264 threads with this stack with FAT LOCK:

```
    "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '100' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'": non-Java thread
    "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '101' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'": non-Java thread
    "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '102' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'": non-Java thread

each ExecuteThread have the same thing:

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '110' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=842 idx=0x48 tid=28341 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0xa03777f0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.wait(Locks.java:1973)[inlined]
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:205)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:233)[optimized]
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0xa03777f0[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"Thread-1" id=11 idx=0x4c tid=16134 prio=5 alive, sleeping, native_waiting, daemon
    at java/lang/Thread.sleep(J)V(Native Method)
    at com/singularity/util/org/apache/log4j/helpers/FileWatchdog.run(FileWatchdog.java:104)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '103' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=850 idx=0x50 tid=28350 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x9cf6ba30[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.wait(Locks.java:1973)[inlined]
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:205)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:233)[optimized]
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0x9cf6ba30[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
```

And a few of them (7) are in standby state with this full stack with FAT LOCK:

```
"[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '105' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=852 idx=0x6c tid=28352 prio=5 alive, waiting, native_blocked, daemon
    -- Waiting for notification on: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0xa02d3520[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at jrockit/vm/Locks.wait(Locks.java:1973)[inlined]
    at java/lang/Object.wait(Object.java:485)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.waitForRequest(ExecuteThread.java:205)[inlined]
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:233)[optimized]
    ^-- Lock released while waiting: weblogic/work/ExecuteThread@0xa02d3520[fat lock]
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace
```

And one thread was in "STUCK" state with this stack:

```
"[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'": non-Java thread
    at jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal(JLjava/lang/Object;)Z(Native Method)
    at java/lang/Object.wait(J)V(Native Method)
    at weblogic/rjvm/ResponseImpl.waitForData(ResponseImpl.java:90)
    at weblogic/rjvm/ResponseImpl.retrieveThreadLocalContext(ResponseImpl.java:153)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherProxy.unmarshalResponse(DispatcherProxy.java:241)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherProxy.dispatchSyncTranFuture(DispatcherProxy.java:134)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:334)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSyncNoTran(DispatcherWrapperState.java:381)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherWrapperState.dispatchSync(DispatcherWrapperState.java:249)
    at weblogic/jms/dispatcher/DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:43)
    at weblogic/jms/frontend/FEConsumer.<init>(FEConsumer.java:296)
    at weblogic/jms/frontend/FESession$2.run(FESession.java:1076)
    at weblogic/security/acl/internal/AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic/security/service/SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic/jms/frontend/FESession.consumerCreate(FESession.java:1072)
    at weblogic/jms/frontend/FESession.invoke(FESession.java:3027)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherImpl.syncRequest(DispatcherImpl.java:185)
    at weblogic/messaging/dispatcher/DispatcherImpl.dispatchSync(DispatcherImpl.java:220)
    at weblogic/jms/dispatcher/DispatcherAdapter.dispatchSync(DispatcherAdapter.java:43)
    at weblogic/jms/client/JMSSession.consumerCreate(JMSSession.java:3017)
    at weblogic/jms/client/JMSSession.setupConsumer(JMSSession.java:2775)
    at weblogic/jms/client/JMSSession.createConsumer(JMSSession.java:2717)
    at weblogic/jms/client/JMSSession.createDurableSubscriber(JMSSession.java:2513)
    at weblogic/ejb/container/internal/JMSConnectionPoller.setUpTopicSessionAt(JMSConnectionPoller.java:1530)
    at weblogic/ejb/container/internal/JMSConnectionPoller.setUpTopicSessions(JMSConnectionPoller.java:1316)
    at weblogic/ejb/container/internal/JMSConnectionPoller.createJMSConnection(JMSConnectionPoller.java:2311)
    at weblogic/ejb/container/internal/JMSConnectionPoller.connect(JMSConnectionPoller.java:808)
    at weblogic/ejb/container/internal/MDConnectionManager.timerExpired(MDConnectionManager.java:179)
    at weblogic/timers/internal/TimerImpl.run(TimerImpl.java:284)
    at weblogic/work/SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic/work/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
```

And this one Executed thread 2

```
"ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=55 idx=0xc8 waiting for java/lang/String@0x9c312a30 held by:, "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=54 idx=0xc4 tid=16428 in chain 2, , Chain 4:, "ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=56 idx=0xcc tid=16432 waiting for java/lang/String@0x9c312a30 held by:, "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=54 idx=0xc4 tid=16428 in chain 2, , Open lock chains, ================, Chain 1:, "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=34 idx=0x80 tid=16400 waiting for weblogic/jms/client/JMSXASession@0x91a97650 held by:, "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" id=35 idx=0x84 tid=16401 (waiting on notification), , Chain 2:, "ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" id=53 idx=0xc0 tid=16426 waiting for java/lang/String@0x9c312a30 held by:, "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'": non-Java thread
```

This is the Executed thread 1

```
"ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'": non-Java thread
    at jrockit/ext/epoll/EPoll.epollWait0(ILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)I(Native Method)
    at jrockit/ext/epoll/EPoll.epollWait(EPoll.java:123)[optimized]
    at weblogic/socket/EPollSocketMuxer.processSockets(EPollSocketMuxer.java:156)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.run(SocketReaderRequest.java:29)
    at weblogic/socket/SocketReaderRequest.execute(SocketReaderRequest.java:42)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:145)
    at weblogic/kernel/ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:117)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
```

In every THREAD I see a "FLAT locks" from jrockit/vm/Threads.waitForNotifySignal waiting for a signal to remove the lock, but I can't find the source (Maybe the ExecuteThread 2 held by ExecuteThread 1).

The ExecuteThread 2 seems to be "held" by the ExecuteTread '1', why?

The "weblogic.socket.Muxer" seems to read incoming requests on the server and incoming responses on the client is it correct? Is it possible to known what he is waiting for?

Thanks for your help, i'am lost :/

Regards,

C

Comment: Socket Muxers are listening to incoming requests. Thread dumps always show a lock chain with socket muxers but it is the WebLogic handle them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation about Socket Musers, i think i get it ;)

it's maybe a stupid question:
should I be worried about this kind of BEA Warning?
"BEA-002936 maximum thread constraint ClusterMessaging is reached"

One of my co-worker asked me why this alert happened, but I can't find the root cause because in the thread dump i can't find anything strange maybe i just need to change a parameter for this alert

Comment: Questions are never stupid...answers sometimes. ;o)
You can ignore BEA-002936 warning messages. They can be ignored. You can create a log filter to get rid of them if you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emmanuel,

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

For better clarification:

> **BEA-002936**
>
> **Info**: maximum thread constraint constraintName is reached Description: maximum thread constraint constraintName is reached
>
> **Cause**: The number of threads assigned to this work manager has reached the configured value in the maximum threads constraint
>
> **Action**: no action needed

> **BEA-002937**
>   **Info**: maximum thread constraint constraintName is no longer reached
>
> **Description**: maximum thread constraint constraintName is no longer reached
>
> **Cause**: The number of threads assigned to this work manager has dropped below the configured value in the maximum threads constraint
>
> **Action**: no action needed

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e14397/WorkManager.html